# MSVCP120D.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, visual-studio, c++, windows-libraries

I made a C++ program in Visual Studio, and I wanted to show it to my friend. However, I'd never set up the visual C++ runtime libraries before, and so I started up a windows 8.1 virtual machine and tried to install the libraries there, from [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=40784). However, after installing them, the VM gave this error;

[image]

What do I need to install to get the program to work correctly? (the executable is called Main.exe, by the way.)

Comment: Note that while this question is entirely on-topic on SU, you might get a quicker response on SO, and also not be subjected to close votes from anyone who assumes a Visual Studio question is about code.

Answer (score 3):

`MSVCP120D.dll` is the Debug enabled version of the [Standard C++ Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscc687y.aspx), which is not licensed for redistribution.

Compile your code in Release mode, and the dependency will change to `MSVCP120.dll` (note, no D), which the user should have, now that you have installed the MSVCRT redistributable package.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to compile it in release mode, but I followed the instructions from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2650113/2373676) and changed the project configuration from Debug to Release, and then rebuilt it. However, after moving the new executable over and running it, I got exactly the same error as before, with MSVCP120D.dll missing and all.

Comment: see if you find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890458/compile-c-in-vs-without-requiring-msvcp120d-dll-at-runtime